# How to get exact match in semi-complicated countifs() formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, textmatching

First, the formula I'm currently using:

`=countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AA:AA,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))+countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AB:AB,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))+countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AC:AC,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))+countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AD:AD,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))+countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AE:AE,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))+countifs('page1'!AF:AF,$L6,'page1'!AF:AF,"="&RIGHT(M$2,3))`

Alright, now, what I'm attempting to match against is:

```
I-A
II-A
III-A
etc
```

The problem is that if within the ranges I'm looking there are patterns that loosely match the terms above, then the countifs() returns true without fully evaluating the entire string. In other words, I am specifically looking for strings "II-A" in said formula, but countifs() is returning counts for all strings that are not only "II-A" but "I-A" as well. Naughty countifs()!

Is there an easy way to do this. I seriously do not want to have to rethink/rewrite these formulas. I found a method called exact() but rolling that in just seems painful. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

### EDIT EDIT EDIT

Here's a test table...

```
   A       B        C
1 I-A   II-A    1-Jan
2 II-A  III-A   2-Jan
3 I-A   II-A    2-Jan
4 I-A   II-A    3-Jan
5 II-A  III-A   4-Jan
6 I-A   II-A    7-Jan
```

`=COUNTIFS($CC:$CC,"="&$C2,$AA:$AA,"="&$A1)+COUNTIFS($CC:$CC,"="&$C2,$BB:$BB,"="&$A1)`

This mock test formula results in 0, but what I'm looking for is 1, because one I-A occurs on 2-Jan...

The same formula for 1-Jan should give me 1, and 1 for 3-Jan, and 7-Jan respectively. I'm trying to count the number of I-A, II-A, III-A for each date IE answering the question, "How many times does II-A occur on Jan-2, and then on Jan-3, etc?" Note that this is test data. The actual data actually has many more dates and many more kinds of values in place of the contents of the cells. For example purposes, however, this example data should be sufficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jim, see my comments below, looks like you have a typo in your COUNTIFS function addresses.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is COUNTIFS that is the problem.  A very simple example using Excel 2008 gives:

Cells: A2 - A4 have I-A, II-A, III-A in them respectively.  Same values in C2-C4.

In D2 I have:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$4,"="&$A3)
```

and this yields 1 which is the correct answer for an exact match.  Without pulling your formula apart it does have RIGHT(M$2,3) in there which will only match the last 3 characters, is that is what could be happening?

Hope this helps,

Dave

Comment: Well, the right() method is being used to extract a portion of the contents of the cell. The contents of that cell read something like "Cat II-A". I'm trying to put together a better example.

Comment: Alright, so I'll clarify. Let me fix the actual example given in the OP, though.

Comment: Hi Jim, the only thing wrong that I can see with your formula is that the addresses for the columns are wrong.  You have $CC:$CC and $AA:$AA for example, instead of $C:$C and $A:$A.  If you change them you get 1 as the answer.  Hope this solves it for you.  Dave

Comment: ...also if you want to strip off the first 4 chars use RIGHT(M$2,LEN(M$2)-4)... Dave

Comment: Ok. So it appears that I can't do full column references for it to work IE this works: =COUNTIFS($C1:$C10,"="&$C2,$A1:$A10,"="&$A1)+COUNTIFS($C1:$C10,"="&$C2,$B1:$B10,"="&$A1)... But why?

Comment: Hi Jim, $A:$A is the full column address and works for me as a full column. Dave